# In vscode I am receiving "invalid WIN32 path error" when trying to compile a LaTeX file

Tags: visual-studio-code, windows-10, latex

I am trying to compile a .tex file in vscode.

It compiled yesterday. It can be compiled from the command line and using other editors.

I can compile other files, just nothing in a certain subdirectory. That directory has not manually changed location, ever.

When I try to compile the latex recipe never starts. Instead it spins with an error

```
"c:\path to file\filename without extension\c:\path to file contains invalid WIN32 path characters"
```

It doesn't matter if I move the source tree.

Is there a cache I can clear somewhere or something else I can do to resolve?

Yes, I have tried turning it off and on again.

Comment: I'm sure you didn't plug/unplug the computer though :)

Comment: can you post _real_ examples of dirs that work and dirs that don't?